# How do I make a good post request for Sabre Rail Search Single Trip? I get 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST' Bad Request Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, request, sabre

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/rest_apis/ground/content_services_rail/search_single_trip/reference-documentation

"requestBody" with "searchCriteria" is required in the POST request.

If I don't specify the "requestBody" I get the "no access privileges" error.

But when I add "requestBody" to the params I get [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400] {
code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', ...

I don't get it. How should I incorporate "requestBody" with "searchCriteria" into the code and into the request? In the JSON example they even put it inside "payload", when I put "searchCriteria" inside "payload" instead of params.requestBody I get "no privilages" error.

I can't seem to get a single successful response no matter where I put the "requestBody" and "searchCriteria".

```
const optionsToUse = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: "https://api-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com/v1/rail/offers/journeys/1S",
  params: {
    marketingCarrierCode: "1S",
    requestBody : {
      "searchCriteria" : [ {
        "journeyCriteria" : {
          "departure" : {
            "locationId" : "FRPLY",
            "dateTime" : "2022-08-02T07:07"
          },
          "arrival" : {
            "locationId" : "FRLPD"
          }
        },
        "passengerCriteria" : [ {
          "passengerCode" : "ADULT"
        } ]
      } ]
    }
  },
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer " + access_token
  }
}

axios.request(optionsToUse).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wyrun,

You need to pass your body in data not in params and remove your params attribute because the marketingCarrierCode is a param inside the url, not a query param :

```
const optionsToUse = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: "https://api-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com/v1/rail/offers/journeys/1S",
  data: {
    "searchCriteria" : [ {
      "journeyCriteria" : {
        "departure" : {
          "locationId" : "FRPLY",
          "dateTime" : "2022-08-02T07:07"
        },
        "arrival" : {
          "locationId" : "FRLPD"
        }
      },
      "passengerCriteria" : [ {
        "passengerCode" : "ADULT"
      } ]
    } ]
  },
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer " + access_token
  }
}
```

(Axios documentation for request config https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config)